# SQL Query: How to multiply values in Table A by Value in Table B?

Tags: sql

I'm drawing a blank on the below issue.

```
   Table A             Table B
Item    Amount      Item    Multiplier 
Bread   100         Bread   1.7
Milk    100         Cheese  1.8
Cheese  100
```

I need to run a query that returns each Item in Table A as well as the corresponding Amount * Multiplier. The caveat is that any item without an entry in Table B should default to a multiplier of 1.5. The query results should look as follows:

```
   Query Results          
Item    Amount      
Bread   170         
Milk    150         
Cheese  180
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
SELECT A.ITEM, A.AMOUNT * COALESCE(B.Multiplier, 1.5) Amount
FROM TableA A
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB B ON A.ITEM = B.ITEM
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for the prompt response.